# cannot use google drive api "(401) Invalid Credentials", even though authentication succeeded

Tags: google-drive-api

I am creating a browser based application, based on php.  I send the user to a google permissions page via a url i get from Google_Client() -> >createAuthUrl().

The user then allows the permissions I requested and gets redirected back to my site, where I use the query parameter (code) to generate an accesstoken.  After setting the accesstoken, I attempt some google drive api calls, but the calls always fail (401) Invalid Credentials, no matter what api calls i attempt to use.

When inspecting the rest url google is using, i see it always returns the following:

```
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "internalError",
                "message": "Internal Error"
            }
        ],
        "code": 500,
        "message": "Internal Error"
    }
}
```

Here is my code:

```
require_once 'src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'src/contrib/Google_DriveService.php';
require_once 'src/contrib/Google_Oauth2Service.php';

class Google_drive 
{

    var $array_values = array();
    var $CI;
    var $client;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->CI = & get_instance();

        $client = new Google_Client();
        // Get your credentials from the APIs Console
        $client->setClientId('12340XXXXX26.apps.googleusercontent.com');
        $client->setClientSecret('4vJU1RVcXXXXXX71levO5wF-');
        $client->setRedirectUri('http://test.elemental.co.za/drm/requestlists/google_drive');
        $client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'));

        $service = new Google_DriveService($client);

        if (!$this->CI->input->get('code')) // (this is the query string parameter ?code=
        {
            redirect($client->createAuthUrl());
        }
        //Request authorization
        $authCode = $this->CI->input->get('code'); // (this is the query string parameter ?code=
        // Exchange authorization code for access token
        $accessToken = $client->authenticate($authCode);
        $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
        $files = $service->files->list(array())
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, so it turns out that i was missing the client->setDevolperKey('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'),
something that I cant seem find anywhere in googles documentation, even now that I know what it is.